# SQL View data in Spring Boot JPA does not come properly

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

We have a requirement for generating *CSV reports*, for achieving the same we have used SQL Views. The view provides correct data on mysql workbench but the same data changes when called via *JPA repository* `findAll()` method. It starts repeating same data for one column in response.

We have used **Spring Boot Version - 1.5.8**

Why the data differs when executed in MYSQL Workbench and JPA repository?

Comment: Very vague question, one guess is that @Id  defined for the entity mapping the view is not correct.

Comment: @garfield , apologies for being very vague, let me give an example- suppose there are two tables, A and B joined together to form a view. Where A has one-to-many mapping with B, which means for every repeated value of A there will be a different value for B.
The different value of B is not appearing, it gets repeated for the number of times B has value.

Comment: An entity must have a unique id which is not a necessary condition for a view. From your description above the view can have a candidate key in the form of a composite (A.key, B.key) so perhaps you may come up with a similar composite key for the entity mapping the view.

Comment: @garfield thank you for your help.  It was a issue with composite key and '@Id' annotation. I used '@Id' annotation only one of the fields' of the composite key. But after your guidance I modified the View and created a separate key itself with '@Id' annotation and it worked like charm.